# Weird mmap failed size 2147483648 with AVPlayer for mp3 link

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, avplayer, mmap

I am using AVPlayer to play some mp3 link, the file is just 1.8MB and I could download it, browser can also play it, but the app crashes (for other mp3 links it works) with the following information:

> (951,0xac82aa28) malloc: *** mmap(size=2147483648) failed (error
>   code=12)**
>    error: can't allocate region
>   ** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

It fails even if the mp3 links is played first (ie there is no previous players created and not released in memory), so why do I still get the memory not enough error? I was thinking that it might be caused by the HTTP header when getting the stream, but the header looks fine:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Length: 1872792

Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:19:10 GMT

Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

Last-Modified: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 02:06:19 GMT

Etag: "1c9398"

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Cache-Control: max-age=0

Expires: Mon, 05 Aug 2013 00:19:10 GMT

Connection: close

Content-Type: audio/mpeg

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: That number is very suspicious: 0x80000000/0b10000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: In a 32bit app, you cannot usually `mmap()` 2GB as continous section of virtual memory (there's no gap in the address space large enough for that). Which `malloc()` implementation are you using ? Most _don't_ fall back to `mmap()` hence your error message is ... unusual.